# How to replace SCNNode with another on the same place with points on marker?

Tags: ios, scenekit, uitapgesturerecognizer, arkit, scnnode

My AR example app shows heart 3D model in touch. When retouching on the 3D model I want to show parts marker on the heart. For that, I created 2 models one for showing plain another one for showing heart with parts arrow marker.

But I don't know how to place a marker on the exact place where I placed the previous node. A node will be changed only on tap, scale, transformation, position everything has to be same.

Can you tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a empty node on tap and add your heart model as its child node. Now on next tap remove heart node and add marker node as child node.